# Matrix multiplication between CV_8UC3 and CV_32FC3

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to make matrix multiplication between image and mask. I want multiply in HSV value with 0.3. I think, the problem is between `CV_32FC3` and `CV_8UC3`, but when I convert, still not work correct. 
How can I do? Here is my current code:

```
Mat mask = Mat(frame.size(), CV_32FC3, cv::Scalar(1, 1, 1));
cv::fillConvexPoly(mask, pts, 3, cv::Scalar(1,1,0.3));
cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_BGR2HSV);
frame.convertTo(frame, CV_32FC3);
cv::multiply(frame,mask,frame);
frame.convertTo(frame, CV_8UC3);
cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_HSV2BGR);
```

If I do only this, see the mask is ok - white and black changes:

```
Mat mask = Mat(frame.size(), CV_32FC3, cv::Scalar(1, 1, 1));
cv::fillConvexPoly(mask, pts, 3, cv::Scalar(0,0,0));
imshow("mask", mask);
```

Comment: I'm not a CV expert, but `frame.dot()` seems to be a dot product, which also adds all the elements after multiplication, and probably an assignment operator overload of `frame` makes the assignment work. Are you sure `dot` provides element-wise multiplication?

Comment: OK, I think I'm right... I just checked the [OpenCV manual](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-dot).

Comment: If I use `frame.mul()` is the same.

Comment: Well, one problem at a time... first, use the correct multiplication and then ask why that is not working. Please spend some time verifying that everything is going according to your plan.

Comment: Did I not tell you about `split` and `merge`?

Comment: @Zindarod yes. But here I want use only mask and image, without copy of image.

Comment: @NejcGalof Btw, if you know how to use STL Algorithms, consider using [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) to do element-wise multiplication. That's another way of doing it efficiently.

Comment: You want to multiply the 3rd hsv channel with 0.3, right? There's no copying needed, just split the hsv, multiply 3rd channel with 0.3 and merge back to original image.

Comment: @Zindarod But I want multiply only pixels inside poly. I defined pixels with mask. I don't need to change all pixels.

Comment: Then use `cv::multiply(frame,mask,frame)`.

Comment: I use. But image is not convert. Problem must be in converting. I don't know if converting in  `HSV` or in  `CV_32FC3`. Colors change in not normal. If I not convert to `CV_32FC3`, multiply say `mask` and `frame` must be same type.

Comment: from OpenCV documentation: **If the matrices have more than one channel, the dot products from all the channels are summed together.**

How do you validate your result? by visualizing it?

Comment: @Tom I change this line. It's true. But mean problem is the same.

Comment: @NejcGalof how do you check your results after the multiplication?

Comment: Can you provide an example image and the result? It is hard to understand what is not working... or what do you mean for not working? does it give you random numbers? or maybe just slightly different as expected? or does it give you error? or nothing changes at all? have you checked a pixel value before and after the the value is applied?

Comment: I see on image is not changes, when I use `multiply`. If I show only mask, is correct. On image in output i don't see any changes.

Comment: And I try in BGR, and anyway not changes.

Comment: @NejcGalof can you add the code for the result validation?

Comment: The problem is, image stop updating outside function after `convertTo`. I must send into function `Mat&` not just `Mat`